# AuthLogic sessions only work on localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm running pow locally along with localhost:3000 (for debugging purposes). For some time I was able to create user sessions fine with authLogic on http://app.dev.

At some point however, I discovered that I was only able to login using http://localhost:3000. The login also doesn't work on Heroku.

I've tried messing with Rails.application.config.session_store :domain, setting it to 'app.dev'. No luck.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured this out. I had http_basic_auth turned on and AuthLogic wasn't happy. Simply turning it off solved the problem.

Figures.